# `account.access_token` & `account.refresh_token` is `undefined` when using Twitter Provider with `next-auth`?

Tags: twitter, jwt, twitter-oauth, next-auth

I am following [this tutorial](https://spacejelly.dev/posts/how-to-make-twitter-api-requests-with-nextauth-js-session-tokens/) & am unable to get the value of `access_token` & `refresh_token` from [next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/). My callback function looks like:

```
callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
      if (account) {
        token[account.provider] = {
          accessToken: account.access_token,
          refreshToken: account.refresh_token,
        }
        console.log(token[account.provider])
      }

      return token
    },
  },
```

It currently logs `{ accessToken: undefined, refreshToken: undefined }` to the console.

This is how it's shown [in the docs when using jwt callbacks](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback) but it's not working for me.

I have made a complete reproduction on branch `next-auth-with-twitter-api-v2` → https://github.com/deadcoder0904/twitter-api-v2-3-legged-login-using-next-connect/tree/next-auth-with-twitter-api-v2

## Edit:

It looks like it works on v3. See branch `next-auth-v3-with-twitter-api-v2` → https://github.com/deadcoder0904/twitter-api-v2-3-legged-login-using-next-connect/tree/next-auth-v3-with-twitter-api-v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `access_token` got renamed to `oauth_token` & `refresh_token` got renamed to `oauth_token_secret`:

```
callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
      if (account) {
        token[account.provider] = {
          accessToken: account.oauth_token,
          refreshToken: account.oauth_token_secret,
        }
      }

      return token
    },
  },
```